# Nothing is being displayed on the webpage using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Its just basic react-app I'm trying to build. I am unable to see anything on Home and About page. The code is compiled and no errors are found. Here goes the code:

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home.js'
import About from './About'

function App() {
return (
<Router>
<div className="App">
Hi
<div className='content'>
<Routes>
<Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
<Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
</Routes>
</div>
</div>
</Router>
 );
}
export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import './App.js';
const Home = () => {
 return (
  <div className='Home'>Home page!</div>
);
}
export default Home;
```

**About.js**

```
const About = () => {
return (
<div className="About">
<h2>Add about page</h2>
</div>
);
}
export default About;
```

This is the image of the package.json - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChcjX.png

Comment: What exactly is the issue? I don't see any overt issues with this code. How are you running the app?

Comment: in `App.js` remove `js` of `import Home from './Home.js'`

Comment: Also remove the import of App.js from Home component

Comment: What do you have in your index.js file?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce any rendering issues with your code copy/pasted into this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nothing-is-being-displayed-on-the-webpage-using-react-router-dom-7uj4f9?file=/src/App.js:210-274).

Comment: I am running it from Visual studio terminal. Removed the import of App.js from Home component, removed js in '.Home.js' , still not able to see any display in the webpage

Comment: Running *what* exactly?

Comment: im giving 'npm start' at the project folder location

Comment: Can you share your package.json file so we can see your exact dependencies and scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is missing `react-router-dom` as a dependency.

[image]

Run `npm i -s react-router-dom@6` to install the latest v6 version and update the package.json file.

Then restart the app: `npm start`.

Comment: I installed the latest v6 version of react-router-dom using the command you had provided. How do i update the package.json ? is there a command to update package.json ? After installing react-router-dom, i just gave 'npm start' and its showing error - Missing script "start"

Comment: @YagneshwarD Are you sure you are in the same directory as the package.json file? The screenshot you share has a `"start"` script. With `npm i -s react-router-dom@6` the `-s` flag is what saves/updated the package.json file.

Comment: Ok, i resolved the missing script start issue. Then also i am unable to see any data on the webpages :(

Comment: @YagneshwarD What data is there to see on the pages? The code in your examples are rendering simple text.

Comment: I had to create a new app and try installing the 'react-router-dom' and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks @Drew Resse for your inputs.

Comment: @YagneshwarD Ok, glad it is all working for you now. Cheers and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing React in your files from react package, better to import it. And remove App.js import from Home.js file.

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home.js';
import About from './About';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        Hi
        <div className="content">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const Home = () => {
  return <div className="Home">Home page!</div>;
};
export default Home;
```

**About.js**

```
import React from 'react';
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div className="About">
      <h2>Add about page</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
export default About;
```

Comment: I tried everything you had told, still nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Try replacing your code with my code in your files

Comment: If OP is running React 18 then explicitly importing React isn't necessary. Check for yourself [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nothing-is-being-displayed-on-the-webpage-using-react-router-dom-7uj4f9?file=/src/App.js:210-274).